# Transitive sets and power sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently studying set theory and came across this statement here.

*If a set A is a transitive set, then P(A) (its power set) is also a transitive set.*

A set $S$ is called a transitive set if the elements of its elements are elements of $S$.

Could anyone give me a hand on proving this?

I tried some examples and started with the transitive set $A = \{0, \{0\}\}$. However the power set of this would be $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ \{0\}, \{\{0\}\}, \{0, \{0\}\}, \emptyset \}$ and it doesn't seem to be a transitive set which contradicts the statement above. Am I doing anything wrong with my example?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is $0=\emptyset$? Why is above set not transitive?

Comment: I think zero wasn't the best urelement to use. my bad. In this case, zero was meant to refer to the integer rather than an empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your definition of a transitive set is incomplete. It must also be true for a transitive set $S$ that any element of $S$ that is not an urelement is a subset of $S$. Urelements are objects that aren't sets themselves. So in your example, $0$ is not a urelement.

Second, it is not true that the power set of a transitive set is transitive itself, as your very own example demonstrates. What *is* true, however, is that the power set of any transitive set *without* urelements is transitive itself.

For an example of a set that is a transitive set without urelements, try $\{ \{\},\{\{\}\}\}$

Comment: I would have expected that OP identifies $0$ and $\emptyset$, comparing $A$ with its power set.

Comment: The definition of transitive set that I'm familiar with does not require no urelements, but I do remember proving as an exercise the statement in the OP, but with the premise "if A is a transitive set with no urelements, then..."

Comment: @martin.koeberl since he used both symbols, that would be a little weird.

Comment: Oh, right. My above comment is nonsense. But using $0$ for an urelement is not the best choice I'd say. So one has to wait what OP says.

Comment: @JonathanHebert You are right, and I had that wrong. I should state that as a conditional indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late reply. I didn't consider the urelement part of transitive sets which is why I got confused. Your answer clears that up now.